# How to use a SQL EXCEPT statement to pull everything except certain account type

Tags: sql

I run a query to export out to excel but the returned query contains more rows that supported by excel. I want to split up it up into two manageable files. Is it possible for me to run a query that will pull for everything except accounts that contain one attribute?

Example:

Original script:

```
select account as "ICP", 
accountx as "Profile",
ud1 as "Source-L",
ud1x as "Source-T",
amount as Amount, 
amountx as "Source A"
from TABLEX where period = '2021' and partitionkey = X and curkey = 'USD';
```

I constructed this to run for all accountx for example that are retained earnings (which is majority of the rows),

Retained Earning only script

```
select account as "ICP", 
accountx as "Profile",
ud1 as "Source-L",
ud1x as "Source-T",
amount as Amount, 
amountx as "Source A"
from TABLEX where period = '2021' and partitionkey = X and curkey = 'USD' and ACCOUNTX = 'RetainedEarnings';
```

Now I want to run the query for every accountx EXCEPT those that are retained earnings. How can I exclude this? Or is there a similar way to achieve what I am trying to do. Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: So add the proper constraint to the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

**ACCOUNTX <> 'RetainedEarnings'** will select all the rows where ACCOUNTX is not equal to 'RetainedEarnings' :

select account as "ICP",
accountx as "Profile",
ud1 as "Source-L",
ud1x as "Source-T",
amount as Amount,
amountx as "Source A"
from TABLEX where period = '2021' and partitionkey = X and curkey = 'USD' and ACCOUNTX <> 'RetainedEarnings';